# Moving data in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm a bit inexperienced but have a managed to learn how to use my database (access2010) but now I need to remove old files. In the database I have a primary table with multiple tables which stores additional information such as my notes.

I can't seem to figure out how to remove old files based on an input date.
I want to remove all files and the data stored in the dependent tables completely from year 2011 and back after backing up the database.

I've tried a delete query, and I've tried to simply copy and past inside the tables. I know there has to be a way to do this without deleting individual files.

When I run a delete query I get invalid key errors and when I delete files from my primary table, I get errors indicating there are associated data stored in the other tables.

Since I can't seem to delete all data across all tables for a certain date range, can anyone point out what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you have constraints (foreign keys?) that are preventing you from deleting data. We'll need to see your actual error messages to provide any help.

Comment: Yeah actually, I think this was because I had notes on a different table. I have to delete those notes to delete the original file on the table the rest of the data is living. I think you're exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `JOIN` the additional tables to your "primary" table, include a `WHERE` clause to only delete those matching your date range.

For an example, see this answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102738

Comment: You can also look into the "Cascade delete..."  option if you find it easier to tackle each table separately.  https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-edit-or-delete-a-relationship-98b13aa7-3250-41e3-b6cc-54f4f7e69d88